# error building libreoffice with root user: tar Cannot open: Operation not permitted

Tags: build, makefile, root, libreoffice

I got the following error while building libreoffice. I am building as root user with su (root permissions).

```
/usr/bin/make -j 1 -rs -f /media/libreofficeshared/libreoffice-core/libo/Makefile.gbuild \
         \
         \
         \
        all
[build UPK] d6eef4b4cacb2183f2bf265a5a03a354-boost_1_55_0.tar.bz2
tar: libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/rtree_parameters_type_const____indexable_getter_const____value_equal_const____allocator_type_const___.html: Cannot open: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
make[1]: *** [/media/libreofficeshared/libreoffice-core/libo/workdir/UnpackedTarget/d6eef4b4cacb2183f2bf265a5a03a354-boost_1_55_0.tar.bz2] Error 2
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Why is this happening?
I am using Debian 6 on virtualbox.

Comment: You should not build Libreoffice as root!

Comment: @moggi I guess, you are right, but I got the same error when I first tried to build as a non-root user :(

Comment: Somehow your boost build failed with an odd error message. Do you ave enough space on the partition? Otherwise you can use system boost and see if that helps.